# C++ iterate vector randomly

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, vector, random-access

I'm working on a multithreaded program where all threads share some vector (read-only). The goal of each thread is to walk the entire vector. Nonetheless, all threads must visit this vector in a different way.

Since the vector is const and shared among all threads, i cannot use random_shuffle and just iterate over it. For now my solution is to build 
a crossref vector that will contain indices over the shared vector and then
shuffle this vector, i.e.

```
     std::vector<int> crossref(SIZE) ; // SIZE is the size of the shared vector
     std::iota (std::begin(crossref), std::end(crossref), 0); // Fill with indices ref 
     std::mt19937 g(SEED); // each thread has it own seed.
     std::shuffle (crossref_.begin(), crossref_.end(), g); // Shuffle it
```

Nonetheless, doing this reveal some problems (1) it is not very efficient since every thread  needs to access its crossref vector before accessing the shared one, (2) i have some performances issue because of the amount of memory required : the shared vector is very big and i have a lot of thread and processors.

Does anyone has some improvement ideas that will avoid the need of extra memory?

Comment: Accessing a `std::vector` is done in O(1), since it's random access. Also you are not guaranteed that all threads will have different `crossref` `std::vector`, so it may happen, that two threads will iterate over a vector in same manner.

Comment: I would use a single shuffled index stack shared by all threads which is guarded against concurrent access.

Comment: @Zereges - Sure, but the problem is the shared  vector almost fit the cache, so every time a thread access the crossref vector it will invalidate the caches and this is not efficient..

Comment: I also may have mis-read the assignment. Apparently *each* vector must touch *each* element, and *each* one in a different oder. That necessarily requires some data struct for each thread. Potentially only a bool, but still.

Comment: Do you really need the order to be completely random, or just different for different threads?

Comment: @PeterSchneider that would seem to conflict with the requirement *The goal of each thread is to walk the entire vector.* Ah. You found out yourselves :-)

Comment: does each thread need to traverse the entire vector or are they load sharing?

Comment: @PeterSchneider that would defeat the purpose of multithreading because each thread needs its own permutation. Every other thread will have to wait that the current thread uses its permutation.

Comment: @PeterSchneider a shared index stack is going to incur lock penalties. I should think this will be more costly than separate index vectors.

Comment: And the order for each thread has not only to be different, but generated by a mersenne twister? With simple things like different start offsets per thread it would be easier (or "possible")

Comment: @ Peter Schneider - Your solution is quite elegant but all thread must visit the whole vector, if i understand well your solution, each element of the vector will be visited only once...

@ Zereges - It's not a problem if some threads are common sequences since the whole walk of each thread is different

Comment: @UmNyobe exactly I need a permutation by thread!

Comment: Well, if common sequences are not a problem as long as there is something different, just use an offset per thread. With an array of n elements, each thread iterales the indices `x, x+1, x+2 ... n, 0, 1, 2 ... x-1`, and each thread has a different x.

Comment: @deviantfan i don't care about the generator. You can basically see my problem as a graph exploration where all threads have to visit the whole graph(the shared vector) in a different way. With your solution threads will end to explore it in the same ordre (modulo offset)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the algebraic notion of [primitive root modulo n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n).
Basically

> If n is a positive integer, the integers between 1 and n − 1 that are
>   coprime to n form the group of primitive classes modulo n. This group
>   is cyclic if and only if n is equal to 2, 4, p^k, or 2p^k where p^k is
>   a power of an odd prime number

Wikipedia displays how you can generate numbers below `7` using `3` as generator.

[image]

From this statement you derive an algorithm.

1. Take your number `n`
2. Find the next prime number `m` which is bigger than `n`
3. For each of your thread pick a unique random number `F(0)` between `2` and `m`
4. Compute the next index using `F(i+1) = (F(i) * F(0)) mod m`. If that index is within `[0, n]` range, access the element. If not go towards the next index.
5. Stop after `m - 1` iterations (or when you obtain 1, it is the same thing).

Because `m` is prime, every number between 2 and m-1 is coprime to `m` so is a generator of the sequence `{1 ... m}`. You are guaranteed that no number will repeat in the first `m - 1` steps, and that all `m - 1` numbers will appear.

**Complexity :**

- Step 2 : Done once, complexity equivalent to finding primes up to n, ie [sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)
- Step 3 : Done once, you can choose 2, 3 ,4, 5, etc... Which is as low as `O(thread count)`
- Step 4 : `O(m)` time, `O(1)` in space per thread. You dont need to store the F(i). You only need to know first value and last value. This is the same properties as incrementation

Comment: Very elegant solution!

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking about... In cryptography this group is used a lot for asymetric encryption and signature algorithms, where we also want a pseudo-random permutation which should be completely different for each "key" (here `F(0)`).

Comment: Thank  you, this is really elegant!

Comment: There's something I'm not getting. Assume `n` to be 6, then `m` would be 7. If I now pick `2` as my `F(0)`, I'll be only generating `1,2,4`, since I'm always multiplying these by `2`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6):

If I understand well you want to generate a random permutation in a incremental way, *i.e.* you want to call *n* times a function *f* so that it generates all permuted numbers from 1 to *n*, so that function has constant memory.

I doubt it exists if you want to obtain an uniform distribution among the permutations, but you may be satisfied with a subset of the set of permutations.

If this is the case you can generate a permutation by taking a number *p* prime with *n* and calculate for each *i* in [1,n] : `i.p (mod n)`.
For example, if you have n=5 and p=7, then 7%5=2, 14%5=4, 21%5=1, 28%5=3, 35%5=0. You may combine several such functions to obtain something satisfying for you...

Comment: You mean that if every thread has it own different  _p_  prime with n, every thread can iterate the whole vector with its permutation only by doing `for each i in [1,n] : i.p (mod n)`

If this is the case, i can precompute a set of _p_  offline easily, do i understand well?

Comment: Yes, that's it. And if you think such a function does not flush sufficiently, then combine with offset starting point, or compute twice with two different primes. You can also go backward from n to 1, etc. Some different combination may fit well your needs.

Comment: Jean That will not work if the prime number p divide n.

Comment: I suspect this will result in weak randomness. However, OP didn't say something about the quality of the randomness, only that the permutation has to be different among the threads, so this answer satisfies that.

Comment: Yes, it provides a poor randomness.

Comment: The function that @Esus needs cannot be a good random generator: it looses part of its randomness each time it generate a sample.
In effect the last sample has a conditional probability equal to 1.

Answer (score 2):

If memory is your biggest problem then you'll have to swap CPU cycles for memory space.

E.g. c++'s `std::vector<bool>` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) is a bit-array so quite memory efficient.

Each thread could have its own `vector<bool>` indicating wether or not it has visited a particular index. Then you'd have to use CPU cycles to randomly choose an index that it hasn't visited yet and terminate when all `bool`s are `true`.

Comment: And how is search a unsorted bool vector for "false" n times, ie. O(n^2), instead of n single array accesses, is going to make anything faster?

Comment: Well, OP explicitly said that memory was his main problem. You can't have both space efficiency and CPU efficiency.

Comment: Note OP's question **Does anyone has some improvement ideas that will avoid the need of extra memory?**

Comment: Ok, point for you. And yes, making it faster *and* less memory-consuming seems pretty much impossible.

Comment: I'm ready to be less CPU efficient if each thread can have its own permutation with a small extra memory ....

Comment: Clearly the problem is with the last few iterations. You could improve the performance of the, let's say, last 10% of iterations by switching to an index-based version. When reaching the limit, collect the indices of all false-entries, permute them and use them as an index list. Compared to the original algorithm, this preserves the `O(n)` time but still reduces memory consumption. However, the time line will be less "contignous"; when switching the algorithm, the thread pauses its work for some significant time. This may be imperfect, depending on the application.

Answer (score 2):

It seems [this](http://blog.demofox.org/2013/07/06/fast-lightweight-random-shuffle-functionality-fixed/) guy solved your problem in a very nice way.

This is what he says in the first line of the post: *In this post I’m going to show a way to make an iterator that will visit items in a list in a random order, only visit each item once, and tell you when it’s visited all items and is finished. It does this without storing a shuffled list, and it also doesn’t have to keep track of which items it has already visited.*

He leverages the power of a variable bit-lenght block cipher algorithm to generate each and every index in the array.

Comment: Indeed, and it seems that the permutation are better than in previous answers because it mixes algebraic and murmurhash. Am I right?

Comment: It uses murmurhash as rounding function in the Feistel Network iterations, but he also states that you can use any other kind of elaboration. That hashing just gave him good results.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer but it should lead us to a correct solution.

You have written some things which we could take as assumptions:

> (1) it is not very efficient since every thread needs to access its
>   crossref vector before accessing the shared one,

This is unlikely to be true. We're talking about one indirect lookup. Unless your reference data is really a vector of ints, this will represent an infinitesimal part of your execution time. If your reference data is a vector of ints, then just make N copies of it and shuffle them...

> (2) i have some performances issue because of the amount of memory
>   required : the shared vector is very big and i have a lot of thread
>   and processors.

How big? Did you measure it? How many discrete objects are there in the vector? How big is each one?

How many threads?

How many processors?

How much memory do you have?

Have you profiled the code? Are you *sure* where the performance bottleneck is? Have you considered a more elegant algorithm?

Comment: I'm up to 128 threads with 128 dedicated cores. I work with a vector of int that doesn't fill the whole memory, but it's a fair simplification regarding my problem. I've used profiler and i 'm sure that this part is a bottleneck. I also use dedicated memory allocator. 

_Have you considered a more elegant algorithm?_ Yes, but the algorithm is elegant, the problem was about coding efficiently this elegant algorithm.

Comment: Do the values in the vector need to be ints? Could they be shorts?

Comment: No they can't... I also investigate more elaborated solutions with range compression but currently i'm still at experimentation stage.

Comment: Difficult to comment further without knowing more about the problem domain.